# IBM WATSON TEXT TO SPEECH ERROR : : The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Tags: c#, ssl, text-to-speech, ibm-watson

Today i used ibm cloud services that is ibm watson text to speech in my C# WPF application  but when i execute my method then it show an exception that is **The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.**

and my method is that

```
void Example()
        {
            IamAuthenticator authenticator = new IamAuthenticator(apikey: "{APIKEY}");
            TextToSpeechService textToSpeech = new TextToSpeechService(authenticator);
            textToSpeech.SetServiceUrl("URL");
            var result = textToSpeech.ListVoices();
            MessageBox.Show(result.Result.ToString());
        }
```

i don't know what to do next..because i am stuck in this exception

Comment: Which version of TLS does the endpoint support/require. It's probably wanting TLS1.2. You can try setting the version using the answer provided in this question ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40216022/connecting-a-client-to-a-tcp-server-using-tls-1-2

Comment: the error indicates the host didn't like your request and aborted it, probably because your application is indicating and older version of TLS than the server requires. If you place the line of code in the question I linked at the start of your application it should set your process to use 1.2 if available or fallback to 1.1 or 1.0 as needed. Though 1.2 is the preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

use this line of code in static block like constructor and

```
static System.Net.SecurityProtocolType SecurityProtocol
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
```

use this static method.